# Animating a GiF

Tags: html, css, web, gif

I am still a beginner to web development and I am creating a website just to practice different stuff. I currently inserted a GIF of sonic the hedgehog and I want him to run across the web page, very simple left to right. I tried to implement some animation using key frames and not having any luck. Where am I going wrong??

```css
    #sonic-gif {position: relative; animation-name: running; animation-duration:4s;}
      }
     #sonicgif {position: relative; animation-name: running; animation-duration:4s;}
    @keyframes running {
         0% {
           left: 0px;
         }
         50% {
           left: 50px;
         }
         100% {
           left: 0px;
         }
       }
```

```html
    <div id = "sonic-gif" >
       
       <img id = "sonicgif" src ="https://i.postimg.cc/pVmySTLY/sonic-sonic-running.gif" alt = "gif of sonic running">
       </div>**
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/jacobgomez1993/pen/MWjZxeG

Comment: This is the actual website

Comment: The code you've posted works and does what you have described above. The Sonic runs only 50px though, since this is the highest length value in the `left` attribute.
It is unclear what the question is.

Comment: So he actually runs across the screen? He doesn’t on my browser, in all the browsers I have tried he just runs in place. Like a jamook

Comment: On my browser he runs a small bit to the right, then returns to the left and stays there.  It is possible that if the image is taking a bit to load on your connection that the animation has completed by the time the image is actually shown, in which case it would look like he was simply running in place.  Like a jamook.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count

Comment: Yeah I actually had him go a little to the right and go back, like he was moon walking. I was just frustrated because nothing was being animated.

Comment: @JacobGomez It is animated and working – even here on SO in the snippet above. Please increase the left-value to actually see a difference and clear your browser cache if in doubt.

Comment: I cleared cache and increased value still nothing

Comment: What browser are you on exactly?  It would be helpful if you could also include your OS and the browser version number.

Comment: I am using a Fire Fox browser 85.0.2 (64-bit) for acer-002-2.0

Comment: Windows 10 Home

Answer (score 0):

//there was simply mistake some time when animations doesn't works try to change name of animation

```css
#sonic-gif {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#sonicgif {
    position: relative; 
    animation: runningop 5s linear infinite;
    } 
@keyframes runningop{
    0%,100% {
        left: 0%;
    }
    50% {
        left: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id = "sonic-gif" >
    <img id = "sonicgif" src ="https://i.postimg.cc/pVmySTLY/sonic-sonic-running.gif" alt = "gif of sonic running">
</div>
```